# Using Mysql freetext and MATCH AGAINST for product search

Tags: mysql

I have a database structure that contain data about car tires, among other things.
Since this data is spread out into multiple fields (name, inch, profile, et, cb etc.) I created a field that contains everything needed in a search. Examples from this field is the following:

```
Nokian W+ 205/65R15 94T 69512 Frictiontire 2056515F NOK
Fulda TRAMP 4X4 255/55R16 103h 1625555FUTR4X4 561987 Summertire 2555516S FUL
```

Now to the fun part: I thought that I could simply add a FULLTEXT index to this field and search it by matching with what the user writes in a search field.

For example, if a user writes:
    205/65R15 Frictiontire

...I would get a nice listing where the field contains similar data, but no such luck!

Either I thought that MySQL MATCH AGAINST would be simpler to use or I'm not doing it correct.

If I try a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_search
WHERE MATCH(str) AGAINST ('Nokian 1856515 Frictiontire')
```

The first hit I get is:

```
Nokian WR D3 205/65R15 99H XL 69513 Frictiontire 2056515F NOK
```

Sure, both "Nokian" and "Frictiontire" is there but not "1856515". And there are a lot of rows that have all 3 strings in them (300 of 20.000)!
I have tried to make it more complex but without any bigger success and even if I could get it to work I would have lost the simplicity needed to be able to just input a string from a user.

I have tried a lot of different things, both with "BOOLEAN MODE" and "NATURAL MODE".

So in short: I want to match a search string against a field of the info that is needed.
Can this be done in MySQL in a good way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the results from a search, use `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM product_search
WHERE MATCH(str) AGAINST ('Nokian 1856515 Frictiontire') 
ORDER BY MATCH(str) AGAINST ('Nokian 1856515 Frictiontire')  DESC;
```

If you want to require that all three terms are in each row of the result set, use a boolean mode search.

Comment: The order does not help. The first result that contains the 3 terms is around the 30:th row. None of the rows before it has "1856515" in it. I find this rather strange.